# How to get just modification date and time of a file using stat?

Tags: shell, unix, stat

I use `Stat` command to to find the last modification date of a file and result is:

```
File: ‘first.php’
      Size: 145         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
    Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 1771067     Links: 1
    Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      fn)   Gid: ( 1000/      fn)
    Access: 2017-02-28 12:44:32.853785914 +0330
    Modify: 2017-02-27 23:22:11.280625946 +0330
    Change: 2017-02-27 23:22:11.344625946 +0330
     Birth: -
```

What command should I use to show just `first.php  2017-02-27 23:22:11.280625946 +0330` in output?

Comment: Read the manual before asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reading the manual page:

```
man stat
```

And then use the format option:

```
stat -c '%n %y'
```